# Convergence of distances in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences in $(X,d)$. How do i show that $(a_n):=d(x_n,y_n)$ converges?

Here is what i did:
Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be Cauchy sequences,
then $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,x_{n+1})=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(y_n,y_{n+1})=0$. 
I tried using triangle inequality as follows: $d(a_n,a_m)=|a_n−b_m|=d((x_n,y_n),(x_m,y_m))=|(x_n-x_m) + (y_n-y_m)|\leq |x_n-x_m| + |y_n-y_m|= d(x_n,x_m)+d(y_n,y_m),$ wheren, $n,m\in N$

Comment: Isn't this just applying triangle inequality a few times?

Comment: How? Pls. can you show it?

Comment: What are $x_n$ and $y_n$?

Comment: Are real sequences

Comment: So what is the role of $(b_n)$ in your question?

Comment: A cauchy sequence

Comment: This looks like a very fundamental (homework?) question. What did you try in order to solve this? where exactly did you get stuck? To use this site effectively, you must first give your question a serious attempt and provide context for your question. Then you would have picked up the obvious mismatch in the role/definition of a_n....

Comment: There seems to be a little confusion as to the connection of $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$, $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ as the first two only appear implicitly (in the "definition" of $(a_n)$) and $b_n$ is not used at all. Moreover the initialization of $(a_n)$ as an arbitrary Cauchy sequence is a little bit conflicting with defining $a_n = d(x_n,y_n)$. Could you clarify the situation and give the precise relation between the four sequences?

Comment: I am sorry, the question should be... $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}=\{d(x_n,y_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathbb R$ is a Cauchy sequence, and as $\mathbb R$ is complete, then it converges.

Simply observe that
$$
\lvert a_m-a_n\rvert=\lvert d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_n)\rvert\le d(x_m,x_n)+d(y_m,y_n).
$$
Now, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $n_1,n_2>0$, such that
$$
m,n\ge n_1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad d(x_m,x_n)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
and
$$
m,n\ge n_2\quad\Longrightarrow\quad d(y_m,y_n)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
Hence, for $n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$,
$$
m,n\ge n_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lvert a_m-a_n\rvert\le d(x_m,x_n)+d(y_m,y_n)<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: That is exactly what i did! But i am stuck there.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Finally, thank you.